# How to find if value exists in column, and enter if it not found?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with a table and an user-defined variable that may or may not exist in column A.  If it does exist, I need to be able to select that cell.  If it doesn't exist, I need to enter the user-defined variable into the cell.  I think an If/Then/Else statement should work, but I can't figure out how the syntax would work.

Answer (score 1):

Lance was on the right path, but I think he made a small error. If I understand you correctly, the following will do what you need:

```
If rngCell.Value = userVariable Then
  rngCell.Select
Else
  rngCell.Value = userVariable
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
IF userCell <> "" Then
  userCell.Select
Else
  userCell = userVariable
End If
```